# Audio feedback for gtkmm application

Tags: linux, audio, gtkmm

I am developing a `gtkmm` application. I am using linux.

I was wondering if there is a way to provide **audio feedback** to the user when he/she executes some action?

I found a related post on audio feedback for gtkmm [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2005-August/msg00228.html). But it does not provide a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [libcanberra](https://developer.gnome.org/libcanberra/unstable/) for triggering event sounds from the system's sound theme. I don't know if it is available from gtkmm.

If you want more flexibility to play music, etc., then you'll want [gstreamermm](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamermm/stable/).

Comment: thank you, if I wanted the application to give English audio feedback, for people who are sight-impaired, perhaps, will this work?

Comment: You'll want gstreamermm for that.